# HIbernate provided id of the wrong type, expected PK got Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am upgrading an existing Hibernate project from xml mappings to annotations.

I have a simple example which works with xml mappings but I get following error with my annotations:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class hib.StrategyRevision. Expected: class hib.StrategyRevisionPK, got class hib.StrategyRevision
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:196)
    at hib.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class hib.StrategyRevision. Expected: class hib.StrategyRevisionPK, got class hib.StrategyRevision
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:835)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:182)
    ... 1 more
```

[image: Tables]
Here's the original working xml mapping file (simplified for this question):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="hib">

     <class name="PortfolioRevision" table="PortfolioRevisions">
        <id name="revisionId" column="RevisionId" unsaved-value="any">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
    </class>

    <class name="Strategy" table="PortfolioStrategies">
        <id name="id" column="StrategyId" unsaved-value="any">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
    </class>

   <class name="StrategyRevision" table="StrategyRevisions">
        <composite-id>
            <key-many-to-one name="portfolioRevision" class="PortfolioRevision" column="PortfolioRevisionId"/>
            <key-many-to-one name="strategy" class="Strategy" column="StrategyId"/>
        </composite-id>        
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here's my annotated classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PortfolioRevisions")
public class PortfolioRevision {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int revisionId;

    public int getRevisionId() {
        return revisionId;
    }

    public void setRevisionId(int revisionId) {
        this.revisionId = revisionId;
    }        
}



@Entity
@Table(name="PortfolioStrategies")
public class Strategy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="StrategyId")
    private int id;

    public Strategy() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="StrategyRevisions")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name="pk.portfolioRevision", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PortfolioRevisionId")}),
    @AssociationOverride(name="pk.strategy", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="StrategyId")})
})
public class StrategyRevision implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8792535918405463902L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private StrategyRevisionPK pk = new StrategyRevisionPK();        

    @Transient
    public Strategy getStrategy() {
        return pk.getStrategy();
    }

    public void setStrategy(Strategy strategy) {
        this.pk.setStrategy(strategy);
    }

    @Transient
    public PortfolioRevision getPortfolioRevision() {
        return pk.getPortfolioRevision();
    }

    public void setPortfolioRevision(PortfolioRevision portfolioRevision) {
        this.pk.setPortfolioRevision(portfolioRevision);
    }
}



@Embeddable
public class StrategyRevisionPK implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8058688937408537945L;

    @ManyToOne
    private PortfolioRevision portfolioRevision;

    @ManyToOne
    private Strategy strategy;

    public StrategyRevisionPK() {}

    public PortfolioRevision getPortfolioRevision() {
        return portfolioRevision;
    }

    public void setPortfolioRevision(PortfolioRevision portfolioRevision) {
        this.portfolioRevision = portfolioRevision;
    }

    public Strategy getStrategy() {
        return strategy;
    }

    public void setStrategy(Strategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    // override & equals...
}
```

Main method which fails on the find:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("list");
    em = factory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    PortfolioRevision portfolioRevision = new PortfolioRevision();
    em.persist(portfolioRevision);

    Strategy strategy = new Strategy();
    em.persist(strategy);

    StrategyRevision strategyRevision = new StrategyRevision();
    strategyRevision.setPortfolioRevision(portfolioRevision);
    strategyRevision.setStrategy(strategy);        
    em.persist(strategyRevision);

    // TEST
    StrategyRevision strategyRevision2 = new StrategyRevision();
    strategyRevision2.setStrategy(strategy);
    strategyRevision2.setPortfolioRevision(portfolioRevision);
    strategyRevision2 = em.find(StrategyRevision.class, strategyRevision);               
    em.getTransaction().commit();      
}
```

If someone could correct the mistakes in my annotations so they work in same way as existing xml mapping I would be in their debt. I'm using Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML file is a hibernate mapping file and doesn't map 1:1 to JPA - your mapping is failing because you have specified StrategyRevisionPK as the ID, but are passing a StrategyRevision instance instead.  You will have to make changes to how you use things if you want to map this purely in JPA.  You could have kept your original model (I assume the getStrategy method wrapping the pk instance are changes) by just adding the StrategyRevisionPK as a PKClass instead of putting it in the entity as an embeddable.

Something like:

```
@IdClass(StrategyRevisionPK.class)
public class StrategyRevision implements java.io.Serializable {
  @Id
  Strategy strategy;
  @Id
  PortfolioRevision portfolioRevision;
}

public class StrategyRevisionPK implements java.io.Serializable {
  public int strategy;
  public int portfolioRevision;
}
```

The important parts are that the properties/fields in the IDClass must match the names of the properties/fields marked as @Id in the Entity class, but have the type used in the referenced entities.  You then would pass StrategyRevisionPK instances to JPA find operations, but not use them otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris. I tried using @IdClass and passing a populated PK into the find method but I get PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of hib.StrategyRevisionPK.portfolioRevision.I will continue to try and figure out my mistake

Comment: Is it possible to just convert the above XMl mapping to Hibernate annotations? Ideally I don't want to change any existing code just annotate it

Comment: I got it working by doing like you said and passing in a populated PK instead of a Entity to the find method. Thanks for you help I can mess around with ID class now.